# Create multiple pages using data from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to find the way to do this in Ruby on Rails but I dont find the way:

I have a database with three columns: image, food_name, price; and twenty rows with all the info about different foods, their image and their price

I have an erb template and I want to create multiple pages and only modify on each one the image of the food, the food_name and the price (read from the database), the rest of template is the same.

Also the url is going to be different per each row:

```
www.foods.com/burger
www.foods.com/pizza
www.foods.com/spaghetti
```

...

Any idea how to face it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your database table is Food, you can use the [friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to access each show page by the food_name slug.
You can then, in your routes file, route the show page for each food to the root url:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'food#show'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @steev Im gonna try it and see if it works!